# Catch unhandled keyboard events in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsresponder

I'm working on a Cocoa app.

I would like to catch all keyboard events that are not being handled by any responder, and report them to Google Analytics.

For this purpose, I would like to set a custom `NSResponder` that implements `keyDown:` as the next responder of the current last responder.

When and where should I call `setNextResponder:` in order to keep my custom class the last responder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html):

> If no object is found to handle the event, the last responder in the
>   chain invokes [noResponderFor:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/noResponderFor:), which for a key-down event simply
>   beeps. Event-handling objects (subclasses of NSWindow and NSView) can
>   override this method to perform additional steps as needed.